# "java.lang.NullPointerException" error in my generic Dao while configuring unitary testing with DBUnit

Tags: mysql, nullpointerexception, persistence, dao, dbunit

I receive the "java.lang.NullPointerException" error in the following line:

```
miIdioma=miDao.find(Idioma.class, "playa");
```

miIdioma is an object from de class "Idioma" which is composed by the atrributes "palabra" and "idioma"

The Dao file is called IIdiomaDao.java and I would like to use its method:

```
public <T> T find(Class<T> clazz, Serializable id) {
        return entityManager.find(clazz, id);
    }
```

To gain access to this method I declared the variable miDao in the original file

```
private IIdiomaDao miDao;
```

Finally, I am using this method to gain access

```
miIdioma=miDao.find(Idioma.class, "playa");
```

I understood that this error is shown when a variable is not initialized, but I connected the database to my projects and the database data is supposed to be uploaded. To performed the unitary testing I followed these steps:

1. I connected the database

   ```
   public class IdiomaDaoTest {

     private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
     private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/diccionario";
     private static final String USER = "root";
     private static final String PASSWORD = "mypassword";
   ```

   }
2. I imported and red data

> Blockquote

```
public void importDataSet() throws Exception {
      IDataSet dataSet = readDataSet();
      cleanlyInsert(dataSet);
  }

  private IDataSet readDataSet() throws Exception {
      return new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(new File("/home/inta/workspace/JPAconPruebasUnitarias/src/test/sources/FlatXmlDataSet.xml"));
  }

  private void cleanlyInsert(IDataSet dataSet){
      IDatabaseTester databaseTester;
    try {
        databaseTester = new JdbcDatabaseTester(JDBC_DRIVER, JDBC_URL, USER, PASSWORD);
        databaseTester.setSetUpOperation(DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT);
        databaseTester.setDataSet(dataSet);
        databaseTester.onSetup();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
```

Note1: Here, I suppose that the database has been uploaded and therefore initialized it.

My question is: Why miDao is pointing Null? What am I doing wrong?

Note2: my dataset is:

```
<!DOCTYPE dataset SYSTEM "my-dataset.dtd" >
<dataset>
    <idioma palabra="playa" idioma="español"/>
    <idioma palabra="beach" idioma="ingles"/>
    <idioma palabra="platja" idioma="catalan"/>
</dataset>
```

Thank you very much, this community rocks!

Comment: In particular, I wrote this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/24347569/139985 - to explain how to track down the cause of an NPE.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted so heavily? Yes it is a duplicate. Yes it is a total beginner topic. But, no, this question is not bad quality.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind - You have a valid point.  Unfortunately, that's just the way people behave around here.

Comment: @StephenC While I do agree that this question doesn't deserve that many downvotes, the tooltip on the downvote button says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" - Nothing about bad quality of the question itself, and while the question is really well written it does lack research effort (OP could have found the "What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?" by simply searching for it on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is here.

```
private IIdiomaDao miDao;// you have declare the miDao
```

But not initialize it.

Then You will get `NullPointerException` here

```
miIdioma=miDao.find(Idioma.class, "playa"); // NullPointerException since
                                            // miDao is null
```

Initialize `miDao` to avoid `NullPointerException`